# External Drive doesn't want to live in sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, external-disk, remote-disc

I have a remote hard drive (afp/smb) that won't live in the finder sidebar. Actually I have two, and one simply will not live in the finder sidebar. Everything else seems to function normally, including drive access to both drives. I am running mavericks, and mavericks server for the hard drives. How can I get both drives to live in the finder sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the PRAM fixed my issue.

Restart holding option+command+p+r. Hold down the keys until you hear the 2nd startup chime.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/19207534#19207534